# Sitecore XC10.1.2 - Invalid_request

Tags: sitecore-commerce, login

I'm trying to install the `Sitecore XC 10.1.2` locally and I'm facing a issue, that I have no idea what is it.

The installation went well without any error, but when I try to log in in the Admin Page, I got an error, saying that the request were invalid.

In the logfile, I got the following error:

```
Invalid redirect_uri: "https://sxa.storefront.com/identity/signin"
AuthorizeRequestValidationLog { ClientId: "Sitecore", ClientName:
"Sitecore", RedirectUri: null, AllowedRedirectUris:
["{AllowedCorsOrigin}/identity/signin",
"{AllowedCorsOrigin}/signin-oidc"], SubjectId: "anonymous",
ResponseType: null, ResponseMode: null, GrantType: null,
RequestedScopes: "", State: null, UiLocales: null, Nonce: null,
AuthenticationContextReferenceClasses: null, DisplayMode: null,
PromptMode: "", MaxAge: null, LoginHint: null, SessionId: null, Raw:
[("client_id": "Sitecore"), ("response_type": "code id_token token"),
("scope": "openid sitecore.profile"), ("state":
"OpenIdConnect.AuthenticationProperties=tBHwULJMw2L-zKKFiRE3G4hXSKET2cIfKWqRL59--yevCD7j_5mbTxWpWymI0ewNGMJ7Rp0IcScYC4IvGIf2sVVEkbfHE1acqsoz0VR-TRTPcIGtYutN967V0mjjNuBj7mu3CUubg3j2-gNl3tF1jE5eMewL-WLXMJZxdyVzvYNRxYWs9gEmknx80VCpNK9tGJ5SDUAdMBFZgLGTpAt7ZA"),
("response_mode": "form_post"), ("nonce":
"637853795860560397.ZDdlZTRjZDMtNWY3Ni00MDAwLWIxZDItNzNjODM3MjVhMWU4MWQ1NWY0ZDEtZTRjYi00ZDdjLWIwMTktMTkyMThiZmUyNzYz"),
("redirect_uri": "https://sxa.storefront.com/identity/signin"),
("sc_account_prefix": "sitecore\"), ("x-client-SKU": "ID_NET461"),
("x-client-ver": "5.3.0.0")] }
```

[image]

**Does anyone know how to solve this error ?**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Check file in your `Identity Server` instance:

```
{siteroot}\Config\production\Sitecore.IdentityServer.Host.xml
```

and add your `Sitecore URL` to the `AllowedOriginsGroup1` similarly to the example below:

```
<AllowedCorsOrigins>     
    <AllowedCorsOriginsGroup1>https://sxa.storefront.com|https://abc.com</AllowedCorsOriginsGroup1> 
</AllowedCorsOrigins>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer Gaurav, because of your answer I discovery that my problem actually was that I was missing sxa.storefront.